# How to set multiple default values to a dropdown using javascript/jquery

Tags: html-select

I have a dropdown something like this

```
<select id="drp-model">
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Boat</option>
    <option>Motorcycle</option>
</select>
```

And i have an array like this

```
$arr=[1,3]
```

array denotes the index of the selected options.Now i need to set options 1 and 3 by default.Means Car and Motorcycle.

Answer (score 1):

By assigning value attributes to option tag, you can easily achieve with jQuery.

```js
$("#drp-model").val([1,3])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drp-model" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Car</option>
    <option value="2">Boat</option>
    <option value="3">Motorcycle</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can set this value:

```
$('#drp-model')[0].prop('selected', true);

$('#drp-model')[2].prop('selected', true);
```

And add multiple="multiple" in your select